# Make class (which wraps a Map) usable in for-loop in Java

Tags: java

I have a class which is basically wrapper around a Map (that also holds some business logic obviously).
What I would like to be able to do is this:

```
for(Object o: instanceOfMyClass) { ... }
```

So I want to loop over the values of the Map inside my class. Which interfaces do I need to implement in my class (Iterator, Iterable, ...)?
I guess in the interface to implement I somehow need to return an Interator; how can I "reuse" the iterator for the Map (through Map.entrySet()) keeping in mind that I only want to have the values exposed in the iterator of my class?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently iterate over each entry in a 'Map'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)

Comment: Iterating over a Map is a bit different to iterating over a List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as implementing [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html?is-external=true). In your case, you want to implement `Iterable<SomeType>`:

```
public class Main implements Iterable<String>
{
    private final Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    {
        myMap.put("hello", "world");
        myMap.put("aaa", "bbb");
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator()
    {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(myMap).values().iterator();
    }
}
```

Here's a test method, with the output below:

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    for (String entry : new Main())
    {
        System.out.println("Value: " + entry);
    }
}
```

> Value: bbb
>  Value: world

Comment: Argh, you are too fast ! I doesn't have the time to write a complete response :p.

Comment: @ValentinMichalak [cumonnn](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/009/798/sanichedgehog.jpg)

Comment: First of all: thanks for the fast response! But I would like to loop over the VALUE of the Map/Entry only - not the whole Entry. (The key is only used internally for some specific logic and not of interest to the consumer of the class). Any suggestions on this?

Comment: @Daniel then return `values().iterator()` instead of `entrySet().iterator()`.

Comment: @Daniel No problem. I've edited my answer. The concept's the same.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `Iterable` is what allows you to use the `for(Foo f : foo)` syntax, but if you're wrapping a `Map` you might want to implement the `Map.forEach()` method instead. It's a little bit nicer when you can directly address the key and value separately (although the question is now about accessing values only).

```
// Mostly copied from Map.forEach()
// Adjust generic parameters if necessary
public void forEach(BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : internalMap.entrySet()) {
        K k;
        V v;
        try {
            k = entry.getKey();
            v = entry.getValue();
        } catch(IllegalStateException ise) {
            // this usually means the entry is no longer in the map.
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException(ise);
        }
        action.accept(k, v);
    }
}
```

If the default implementation is enough, you can of course just delegate to `internalMap.forEach(action);`.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need to copy the method? Why can't you just defer the call? i.e. `internalMap.forEach(action);`

Comment: @Michael it's more in line with the other answer. Your class wraps a `Map` and you may want different behaviour than just the default `Map.forEach`. Of course delegating the call works fine if you don't need anything special, but there's the implementation in case you do.